# Tedious/unskilled mental work

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Can one used the word *manual work* to define a process of a nonphysical work, where there is no need of skills, it is monotonic and there is a lack of automatization?

For example: Someone creates photographs and then each photo has to be renamed (one by one) without a script doing it. How do you call this part of the job?

I seek a word to address every process of the job that has this feature. For example in this sentence: Photographers are able to avoid "manual work" with modern automatised software.

Comment: We can say "must be renamed manually" since some typing or writing is involved with each renaming.

Comment: Perhaps "menial" is the word you are looking for?

Comment: "Grunt work" or (more rarely) "dog work" may be used to describe such situation.

Comment: this sort of "tedious, computer-related" work is sometimes called "monkey-" work.  along the lines of "you need a photoshop monkey for a few hours".  {conversely though, that can be used sort of sarcastically to refer to a $4000 a day designer, you know.}

Comment: I didn't notice HL already suggested "grunt work".

Comment: And *monotonic* is definitely not the word you're looking for.

Comment: You can also say *must be renamed individually*, which is without ambiguity or implication that anything manual is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task you describe seems more like ***clerical work***, than *manual work*. The term *"clerical work"* has the same boring, mundane, "wish there was a machine to do this for me" connotations as "manual work" - but, it is more appropriate for office-type labor. (As opposed to physical labor)

Comment: Perhaps that's the best general answer - - or maybe, just "office work".  "What sort of summer job have you got?" "Just office work."   Hell, maybe "desk job" is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Might be slightly offensive in some contexts, but suitable here:

**Two-bit paper-pushing**, a mix of two idioms:

**Two-bit** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/two-bit)

> *adj.*
>   1. Informal Costing or worth 25 cents: *"a two-bit cigar"*.
>   2. Slang Worth very little; petty or insignificant: *"a two-bit thief"*.

**Paper-pusher** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/paper-pusher)

> *n. informal.*
>   1. a person who has a routine desk job.
>   2. bureaucrat.

An interesting ELU question: [What does 'two-bit paper pusher' mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/14838/50044)